# Scraping earnings data

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I posted an earlier thread on this, but I've reposted this with some new changes. Basically the website was detecting a web scraper so I added a FireFox user agent. However, my code still seems to be failing. It works for some securities but others it fails.

Note: I've got a sleep in there as I had a for loop for a list of securities (Not shown in code)

```
sec = "BZUN" <- If you replace with ABAC, then it works
print ("Retrieving earnings for ", sec)

url = 'https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/' + sec + '/earnings'
r = requests.get(url, proxies={'http':'62.105.128.174'}, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0'}).text

s = soup(r, 'lxml')

panel = s.find_all('div', {'class':'panel-heading'})
#summary = s.find_all('div', {'class':'data-container'})
print(s)
time.sleep(7)

print(len(panel))
for item in panel:
    period = item.find('span', {'class':'title-period'})
    eps = item.find('span', {'class':'eps'})

    if (item.text).find("Revenue of") == -1:
        revenue = ""
    else:
        revenue = "Revenue of" + (item.text).split("Revenue of")[1].split("/")[0]
```

For example, if I try to request security "BZUN" and I print out the request results, I get a "Please click I am not a robot to continue".

Any ideas?

Comment: First check robots.txt file. Better use framework like scrapy

Comment: Did you use same proxy for both requests?

Comment: I've changed a number of different proxies but get the same results